# QwtPlot with equal axes and auto scale

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwt

I'm developing a Qt5 application with `QWidgets`. I’m using `QwtPlot` from the [Qwt-library](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html) for plotting live data in my tool. I'm setting my plot-axis to auto-scale via `ui.qwtPlot->setAxisAutoScale(axis)`, because I want my plot to automatically adjust to the incoming data.

Now some clients are requesting the possibility, to have a plot with equally spaced axes x and y. I found `QwtPlotRescaler`, which seems to be the right thing for this purpose. I’ve successfully added it to my plot which now has equal axes if needed. (I can disable / enable this functionality by an additional button.)

However I noticed, that the auto-scale functionality is disabled, whenever I activate equal axes. With my dynamically incoming data, I would still like to have a rescaling plot. The axes should be automatically growing and shrinking, whenever the contents (items in the plot) change. So just like the normal autoscaling, but keeping the axes equal in the meantime. How can I archive this?

Do you need any additional information?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your y axis should depend on the x axis, so that you always have a fixed aspect ratio for your coordinate system.

Then Qwt has to adjust the range of y axis and has to ignore the bounding interval of the data in y direction - there is no solution to do both.

What could be done is to add extra margins to the x axis, so that the range of the y axis grows according to the aspect ratio - finally including the bounding interval of the data. But finding good margins to achieve this is not implemented by QwtPlotRescaler.

But if it helps: all what the autoscaler does is to adjust the scales according to the boundingRect of the curves. You can also do this on your own, whenever you change your data.